# Images stored from external API not loading

Tags: plugin-development, images, database, uploads, rest-api

The following is my code I am using to store image that I am getting from an external API using my own plugin. The images, or any media in general, are not loading on the frontend or the Media tab on the WordPress Dashboard.

```
function save_media_as_attachment($media_url, $post_id) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');
    require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

    if (empty($media_url)) {
        return false;
    }

    $temp_file = download_url($media_url);

    if (is_wp_error($temp_file)) {
        return false;
    }

    $file_name = basename($media_url);

    $file_extension = pathinfo($file_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg'; // Default to JPEG

    if (strtolower($file_extension) === 'jpg' || strtolower($file_extension) === 'jpeg') {
        $post_mime_type = 'image/jpeg';
    } elseif (strtolower($file_extension) === 'png') {
        $post_mime_type = 'image/png';
    } elseif (strtolower($file_extension) === 'mp4') {
        $post_mime_type = 'video/mp4';
    }

    $attachment = array(
        'post_title' => sanitize_file_name($file_name),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit',
        'post_mime_type' => $post_mime_type,
    );

    $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $temp_file, $post_id);

    if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
        $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $temp_file);
        wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);

        update_post_meta($attachment_id, '_wp_attached_file', $file_name);

        @unlink($temp_file);

        return $attachment_id;
    }

    @unlink($temp_file);

    return false;
}
```

After doing some research I tried the following

- Regenerating the images by adding the following code inside my theme's `function.php` file

```
function regenerate_all_image_sizes() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attachment',
        'post_status' => 'any',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
    );

    $attachments = new WP_Query($args);

    if ($attachments->have_posts()) {
        while ($attachments->have_posts()) {
            $attachments->the_post();
            $attachment_id = get_the_ID();
            wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, get_attached_file($attachment_id)));
        }
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();
}

regenerate_all_image_sizes();
```

Which did nothing.

- Checking file permissions
- Double checking Image MIME Type
- Checking file integrity and not corrupted when downloaded using URL on my machine
- Also tried disabling `Options -Indexes` from the .htaccess

The above didn't solve the problem as to why the images are not loading.

Comment: When you have an image that doesn't load, what's actually wrong with it? Is the URL to the image correct, i.e. match the path of a file on disk on your server? I'm wondering if you're losing some of the file's path in the uploads folder by overwriting _wp_attached_file. What does the database look like for one of these imported images?

Comment: @Rup the database says there's a file. WordPress Dashboard says there's a file. But I can't see them in the uploads folder directory. I have scoured through all the directories but these files don't exist.

Comment: OK so I guess the problem is that wp_insert_attachment isn't copying $temp_file into the uploads folder, it's just writing a database entry for it, and so when you unlink $temp_file you've deleted the last copy.

Comment: @Rup That is what I am suspecting it's doing. I removed the `unlnk $temp_file` and that did nothing either. So I believe `wp_insert_attachment` is not working.